# Import Method in my C++ DLL and then Export it

Tags: c++, windows, dll

My Tools are :

1. Windows 8 as development environment
2. visual studio 2008 as IDE
3. C++ as programming language
4. windows XP 32bit virtual machine and another 64bit machine as testing machines

what i'm trying to achieve:

i'm trying to override GINA.dll, a windows DLL file that is responsible of Graphical windows logon and so.
my DLL file should have the same function in GINA with the same name, i need some methods to be proxy for the original DLL file when system call method X it should execute the X method in original MSGINA.DLL,

i loaded MsGina.dll using LoadLibrary and i can use GetProcAddress to get original functions addresses, but how to make my method execute the same names method from msgina.dll ?

Note: we can't use macros with inline assembly jmp instruction as it is not supported by X64.

i have seen this : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx
but it made a new function with another name not the same original name,

errors in my trials : 
when i tried to add method such as

```
    __declspec(dllexport) BOOL WlxActivateUserShell(
  _In_  PVOID pWlxContext,
  _In_  PWSTR pszDesktopName,
  _In_  PWSTR pszMprLogonScript,
  _In_  PVOID pEnvironment
);
```

in my .h file and

```
   BOOL WlxActivateUserShell( 
  _In_  PVOID pWlxContext,  
  _In_  PWSTR pszDesktopName,   
  _In_  PWSTR pszMprLogonScript,    
  _In_  PVOID pEnvironment  
  ){
    return true;
}
```

in my .cpp file i get error :

```
Error   1   error C2373: 'WlxActivateUserShell' : 
redefinition; different type modifiers  d:\xxxxxxx.h    23  Gina
```

if i renamed method to WlxActivateUserShellssss for example it doesn't show errors, but that means windows will not be able to use it, it have to has the same name as the original method in msgina.dll

Comment: How do you expect to use ProxyGina.dll in application ?

Comment: i won't, windows loads my gina.dll instead of msgina.dll on startup, i put it in system32 and add a key to regedit and when i restart it loads my gina, so it have to has the same interface.

Comment: Why do you remove `__declspec(dllexport)` ? Do you use `extern "C"` ?

Comment: The correct prototype is `BOOL WINAPI WlxActivateUserShell(...)`. Try adding `WINAPI` (in both places), see if this helps.

Comment: also tried it, and produced the same error as i remember.

Comment: @BlazeBoy I'm quite interested why a regedit key is needed? won't it just work by replacing the original dll in the system32 folder (coz the system component's path is already registered)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used assembly functions to resolve this problem.
The code is available on my [github repo](https://github.com/lin-min/Dll_Wrapper_Gen).
For 32 bit inline is still used, for 64 bit asm file is used.
Details are in this [post](http://m4v3n.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/dll-wrapper-generator/).

Just run the python script and it'll create the project for you.

By the way, there is no need to know the prototype of all the functions except the one you are overriding. Just modify the function you are interested in the generated cpp file.

Comment: thanks Min, the happy news is that i found your amazing application and used it, i achieved the same goal in 1 hour that i tried to do in a month, so really thanks for this app, about using _asm in x64 and the work around in the post, i'm not fan if these workarounds, and i think i can't apply this solution, so i used your app and did what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're trying to write proxy dll. There is no need for assembly.

First, you might want to read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16541/Create-your-Proxy-DLLs-automatically).

Second, microsoft linker has a pragma that allows you to specify function name beign exported and forward functions to another dll.

Pragma looks like this:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:SwapBuffers=gdi32.SwapBuffers") //this will forward call from your dll into original dll you're "overriding".
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:TextOutA=_HookedTextOutA@20") //and this will let you use your own function
```

Proxy dll code could look like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gdi32_fwd.h>
#pragma pack(1)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static HINSTANCE hLThis = 0;
static HINSTANCE hGDI32 = 0;
static TCHAR prtBuf[0x1000];

static BOOL (WINAPI* Gdi32_TextOutA)(
  __in  HDC hdc,
  __in  int nXStart,
  __in  int nYStart,
  __in  LPSTR lpString,
  __in  int cbString
);

static HFONT (WINAPI* Gdi32_CreateFontIndirectA)(
  const LOGFONTA* lplf
); 

extern "C" HFONT WINAPI HookedCreateFontIndirectA(
  const LOGFONTA* lplf
){
    LOGFONTA lf;
    //override data here
    ...

    return Gdi32_CreateFontIndirectA(lplf);
}

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI HookedTextOutA(
  __in  HDC hdc,
  __in  int nXStart,
  __in  int nYStart,
  __in  LPSTR lpString,
  __in  int cbString
){
    //override data here
    ....

    return Gdi32_TextOutA(hdc, nXStart, nYStart, lpString, cbString);
}


//! Attach or detach this proxy.
BOOL WINAPI DllMain( HINSTANCE hInst,DWORD reason,LPVOID )
{
    if( reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH )
    {
        hLThis = hInst;
        hGDI32 = LoadLibrary( "gdi32" );
        if( !hGDI32 )
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    *(void **)&Gdi32_TextOutA = (void *)GetProcAddress( hGDI32, "TextOutA");
*(void **)&Gdi32_CreateFontIndirectA = (void *)GetProcAddress( hGDI32, "CreateFontIndirectA");  
    }
    else if( reason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH )
    {
        FreeLibrary( hGDI32 );
    }
    return TRUE;
}
//! End of file.
```

Header:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AbortDoc=gdi32.AbortDoc")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AbortPath=gdi32.AbortPath")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AddFontMemResourceEx=gdi32.AddFontMemResourceEx")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AddFontResourceA=gdi32.AddFontResourceA")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AddFontResourceExA=gdi32.AddFontResourceExA")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AddFontResourceExW=gdi32.AddFontResourceExW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AddFontResourceTracking=gdi32.AddFontResourceTracking")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AddFontResourceW=gdi32.AddFontResourceW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AngleArc=gdi32.AngleArc")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AnimatePalette=gdi32.AnimatePalette")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:AnyLinkedFonts=gdi32.AnyLinkedFonts")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:Arc=gdi32.Arc")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:ArcTo=gdi32.ArcTo")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:BRUSHOBJ_hGetColorTransform=gdi32.BRUSHOBJ_hGetColorTransform")


#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateEnhMetaFileA=gdi32.CreateEnhMetaFileA")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateEnhMetaFileW=gdi32.CreateEnhMetaFileW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateFontA=gdi32.CreateFontA")
//#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateFontIndirectA=gdi32.CreateFontIndirectA")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateFontIndirectA=_HookedCreateFontIndirectA@4")

...

#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateFontIndirectExA=gdi32.CreateFontIndirectExA")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateFontIndirectExW=gdi32.CreateFontIndirectExW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:CreateFontIndirectW=gdi32.CreateFontIndirectW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:SwapBuffers=gdi32.SwapBuffers")
//#pragma comment(linker, "/export:TextOutA=gdi32.TextOutA")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:TextOutA=_HookedTextOutA@20")

...

#pragma comment(linker, "/export:bInitSystemAndFontsDirectoriesW=gdi32.bInitSystemAndFontsDirectoriesW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:bMakePathNameW=gdi32.bMakePathNameW")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:cGetTTFFromFOT=gdi32.cGetTTFFromFOT")
#pragma comment(linker, "/export:gdiPlaySpoolStream=gdi32.gdiPlaySpoolStream")
```

Comment: yes, i did something similar to teh above in my code, thanks to the awesome application of @min-lin

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://aluigi.org/mytoolz.htm#dllproxyskel).

The link leads to a project that generates a skeleton for a DLL in order to create a proxy.
If I remember correctly, he thought of a lot of things I didn't when I was attempting to do the same thing.

Another thought, read the DEF file documentation in your local copy of MSDN.  I believe there is a keyword in there that basically says "If this def file doesn't define this function (either by function name or ordinal), pass it to this other DLL, at function name or ordinal 'X'".

So if you're trying to replace just function VOID WINAPI DoSomething(VOID) in gina.dll, you can use the keyword I described to proxy all the other functions, whether by name or ordinal

I no longer have a true Windows dev machine, so I can't look it up.  I refuse to use the MSDN website as it's impossible to find anything...